# how do I use a file from my apps documents directory with "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"?

Tags: cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a bunch of mp3's displayed in a UITableView which are located in my apps documents directory.

When I select the row, I want the file to load into AVAudioPlayer and Play.

Can anyone suggest how I would go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out:

```
NSArray *songs;
AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self.player prepareToPlay];

  // Point to Document directory
  NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];

  if (array == nil) {
    // Handle the error
  }
  self.songs = array;
  //[array release];

  //self.title = @"Song List";
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
  NSString *filePath = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

  player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

  [player play];
}
```